# in southern Wales, in the south of Wales, in the southern part of Wales?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Can you tell me which one is correct? And if there is a difference in meaning between them, can someone explain it to me?

and here is the example of the sentence

> Cardiff is the capital and the largest city of Wales, located
>   a) in southern Wales
>   b) in the south of Wales
>   c) in the southern part of Wales

Comment: They are all *correct* (grammatical).

Comment: thank you so much for clarifying me

Comment: @JasonBassford — And how does the poster to know if you are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Hee, hee. All of them are ‘wrong’ in the sense that they are not standard usage in Britain.

> South Wales

…is what people say (and have been saying for a long time, hence New South Wales, the former British colony and now a state in Australia).

See, for example the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Wales), this [tourist guide](https://www.roughguides.com/destinations/europe/wales/south-wales/) and a newspaper, [The South Wales Argus](https://www.southwalesargus.co.uk).

Comment: but can we use South Wales in this example....."Cardiff is the capital and the largest city of Wales,located South Wales'' i don't think this is right...

Comment: Not my downvote but why is saying "southern Wales" wrong? See, [*Southern Wales has a lot to offer whether you are looking for a city break,…*](https://www.southernwales.com/) and [*Other parts of southern Wales were in the hands of various Marcher Lords.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Wales) and from the BBC: [*Tessa Dunlop and Neil Oliver present a guide to southern Wales - from the Severn Bridge to St Davids*](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b07xs2r9)

Comment: @SiranushA you can use it in that example, but you need *in* and personally I wouldn't capitalise *south*. Options a) and b) in your Q are also fine as far as I'm concerned. Option c) is not wrong exactly but those extra words don't really do anything, making it clumsy.

Comment: @Minty okay,,thank you.Can I say ."In South Wales" in the example that i mentioned?

Comment: @SiranushA Yes, that sentence would be perfectly grammatical. To make it read better you might want to consider that we usually say *capital of* but *largest city in*, and whether you can avoid repeating *Wales*.

Comment: @Minty i can't thank you enough,really thank you

Comment: @Mari-LouA — I noticed that. Tourist Board euphemism to avoid the associations of South Wales with coal mining (now dead) and an attempt to compete with North Wales where the most scenic and well-known mountains and coast is. People can downvote me as much as they like — I know I’m right. Perhaps they resent the fact that I present evidence in support of my post, and/or that I’m a Brit. (My wife went to school in Cardiff, incidentally.) I remember answering a question on the use of Mum (rather than Mom) in Britain, which I also documented, and the poster accepted the answer of an American.

Comment: @Dadid it wasn't my downvote either.I am here to gain knowledge and get information,but really want to thank for taking you time and answering me!!!!

Comment: You said *All of them are ‘wrong’ in the sense that they are not standard usage in Britain.* but you haven't really explained why southern Wales is "wrong". I also posted three different sources that support the expression "southern Wales" in the comment above. It doesn't seem to be nonstandard in the slightest. Perhaps if you argued that South Wales was more commonly said, I'd be less puzzled.

Comment: This Brit can confirm that the most common usage, by a large margin, is "in South Wales". [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=south+wales%2Csouthern+wales&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csouth%20wales%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BSouth%20Wales%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSOUTH%20WALES%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csouthern%20wales%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsouthern%20Wales%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSouthern%20Wales%3B%2Cc0) supports this.

Comment: @Mari-LouA — The site is called English Language and Usage. I was helping the poster on usage. Of course there are exceptions, and a particular geographical rather than political description might use Southern. But in general you would get an odd look in Britain if you talked about Southern Wales. (There is a similar US thing that I encountered when living in Chicago for three years, long ago, but now forget. Something like the Middle East, where the usage is different in Britain and the US.)